# Highlight row on Interactive report permanently APEX

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I want to highlight specific rows on Interactive reports in APEX I go to format > Highlight then set the criteria needed for Highlighting desired rows. My problem is that this is a temporary solution. I need these configurations to be set as default so that any user try to use this report results appear highlighted as in criteria set before.any Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is given in documentation read  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21674/ir_using.htm#CHDDDBCG
and accordingly save your highlighed report as a default report which is permenent one.

Answer (score 1):

As a developer, you can save standard reports which will be shown to users by default.
To do this, first generate the report you want to show as default, with all your filtering and highlighting etc.
Then from the Actions menu, select **Save Report**. Then select **As Default Report Settings** from the Save select box.
This option is only available if you are logged into the builder at the same time.

[image]